# flexbox stretch not working in Opera

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, html

How do I get the #body which is coloured red to be 100% height in the normal Flexbox model this is for Opera, does Opera have it's own flexbox model?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body
    {
        height:100%; margin:0px
    }
    body
    {
        display:table; width:100%; height:100%

    }
    body > section
    {
        display:table-row; background-color:#00ff21;
    }
    body > section > #body
    {
        height:100%; background-color:#f00; 
        display:-webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
        -webkit-box-align:stretch; 

        display:flexbox;
        flex-flow:row;
        flex-align:stretch;

    }
    header
    {
        display:table-row; height: 130px; background-color:#ffd800
    }
    footer
    {
        display:table-row;
        height: 160px;
        background-color: #b6ff00;
    }
    body > section > #body > nav
    {
        margin:0px; background-color:#0ff; -webkit-box-flex:1;
    }
    body > section > #body > article
    {
        background-color:#370fff; -webkit-box-flex:9;
    }
    body > section > #body > aside
    {
        background-color:#de09ff; -webkit-box-flex:3
    }
</style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <p>Header</p>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div id="body">
            <nav>
                Left Sidebar
            </nav>
            <article>
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
            </article>
            <aside>
                <p>Right Side Bar</p>
            </aside>
         </div>
    </section>    

    <footer>
        <p>Footer</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which Opera? The "old" one with Presto, or the "new" one with Blink Engine? BTW: The new unprefixed syntax is `display: flex;`. And you "forgot" the IE 10 which likes to have `display: -ms-flexbox;`. ;-)

Comment: I just downloaded the new Opera 12.16 and just using display:flex instead of flexbox doesn't work

Comment: @Netsurfer do you know to make the red #body flex it's height to fill the area

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Mozilla as well so if you know how to flex the #body element leave a message.